# Jquery(Нубский вопрос)

Tags: jquery

Функция работает некорректно. При нажатии на кнопку изменение происходит на миг и не фиксируется

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".a-add-prjct").click(function(){
    $(".a-add-prjct").hide();
    $(".prjct-form").show();

  });
});
```

```css
.prjct-frm-btn {
  display: inline-block;
}

.prjct-form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="" style="color: red;" class="a-add-prjct">+Add project</a> 
<form class="prjct-form" action="" method="">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 50%;" placeholder="project name">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary prjct-frm-btn">Add</button>
  <a href="" class="a-prjct-form prjct-frm-btn">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

Comment: верстка нужна и css желательно

Comment: .a-add-prjct не ссылка ли случайно?

Comment: Добавил html/css, .a-add-prjct - это анкор(ну, или ссылка)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Происходит переход по ссылке и вы видите пустую страницу, решить можно вот так:

`<a  href="#" ...`

Вот рабочий пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".a-add-prjct").click(function(){
    $(".a-add-prjct").hide();
    $(".prjct-form").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.prjct-frm-btn {
  display: inline-block;
}

.prjct-form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" style="color: red;" class="a-add-prjct">+Add project</a> 
<form class="prjct-form" action="" method="">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 50%;" placeholder="project name">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary prjct-frm-btn">Add</button>
  <a href="" class="a-prjct-form prjct-frm-btn">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Какая-то была нелепая ошибка. Аж стыдно. Спасибо за помощь)